# What does Homebrew "-vd" argument mean?

Tags: arguments, homebrew

Could someone please explain the "-vd" argument used for `brew` commands? For example,

```
brew install --build-from-source --with-python -vd protobuf
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to combine flags so `-vd` is shorthand for `-v` and `-d`. Looking at the documentation for Homebrew (https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage) shows us that for `brew install` `-v` means verbose and `-d` means debug.

Comment: So what does "verbose debugging" do? I understand verbose as displaying more details, but how is debugging involved in the installation process?

Comment: Placing the flags together is no different to using them separately it is just a shortcut to save time. This means they function the same as if they were used on their own. The `-d` flag is listed in the documentation as: `If --debug (or -d) is passed and brewing fails, open an interactive debugging session with access to IRB or a shell inside the temporary build directory.` (https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage)